# Как перевести в с++

Tags: c++

```
uses crt;
var n,d,z,x,c,k,a,b:integer;
begin
     write('N:'); readln(n);
     write('D:'); readln(d);
     a:=round(power(10,n-1));
     b:=round(power(10,n)-1);
     for x:=a to b do
     begin
          z:=x;
          k:=0;
          while z>0 do
          begin
               c:=z mod 10;
               if c=d then inc(k);
               z:=z div 10;
          end;
          if  k=0 then writeln(x);
     end;
end.
```

Comment: А с какой строчкой возникли сложности? Вы умеете написать на C++ helloworld?

Comment: @ринат, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Вопрос из серии как собрать самолет, у меня что-то не получается.
Хоть почетче бы задали.

Comment: @ринат, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n,d,z,x,c,k,a,b;

    std::cout<<"N:"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>(n);
    std::cout<<"D:"<<std::endl; 
    std::cin>>(d);
    a = round(pow(10,n-1));
    b = round(pow(10,n)-1);
    for (x=a; x<b; x++) 
    {
          z = x;
          k = 0;
          while (z>0) 
          {
               c = z%10;
               if (c==d) { k++; }
               z/=10;
          }
          if(k==0) { std::cout<<(x)<<std::endl; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Паскалевский `for`, кажется, включает обе границы.

Comment: Это чтобы спрашивающему не было скучно :)

Comment: вместо **z%=10** нужно написать **z /= 10**, иначе хелловорлд упадет в бесконечный цикл на первом же z, не кратном десяти

Comment: @SoloMio вы настолько мелочны, что в ответ на обоснованную критику гадите в тапки с помощью минусов? Фу, как не стыдно

Comment: @DreamChild, вы таки меня спалили :)

Comment: @DreamChild, я не согласен с аргументами критикунов.

Comment: @SoloMio извините, с какими аргументами вы не согласны? С тем, что ваш первоначальный вариант был нерабочим, и падал в бесконечный цикл? Или с тем, что цикл **for** из Pascal у вас неверно переведен на С++? Так эти оба факт верны вне зависимости от того, согласны вы с ними или нет. Поверьте, если бы я хотел именно критиковать ваш код, то не ограничился бы одной только его неработоспособностью, а упомянул бы также ряд других его слабых мест

Comment: @DreamChild, вы ведете к тому, что я должен доделать за нерадивого студента его работу? Да, мой код несовершенен. Да, есть ошибки. Ну пусть он возьмет то что я сделал за него как исходный вариант и доделает?

Comment: @SoloMio,  мне кажется, что

    std::cout<<"N:"<<std::endl;  // печать с последующим вводом с новой строки
    std::cin>>(n);               // а вот тут можно набить оба числа
    std::cout<<"D:"<<std::endl;  // тогда после этого приглашения 
    std::cin>>(d);               // задержки на вводе не будет

не совсем точно моделирует вот это

     write('N:'); readln(n);    { а здесь печать и ввод в той же строке }
     write('D:'); readln(d);    { и из каждой строки читается одно число }

в pascal.

--

Не знаю, конечно, важны ли такие тонкости для ТС.

Comment: @avp, последний раз я писал на паскале в 10м классе.

Comment: >вы ведете к тому, что я должен доделать за нерадивого студента его работу? 

@SoloMio нет я не веду к этому (более того, вообще считаю, что за нерадивых студентов не нужно делать ничего). Я говорю о том, что я сообщил вам об ошибке в вашем коде, после чего вы ее исправили (тем самым косвенно признав ее существование), однако затем почему-то назвали меня критикуном и втихую минуснули мой вопрос, абсолютно не относящийся к обсуждаемой здесь теме. Эти ваши действия выглядят по меньшей мере странно и некрасиво, и совершенно не делают вам чести.